# Trouble grouping result from a max count

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by, max

Here is an exemple of data I could have

```
**Car Name     Brand Name**
 Megan           Renault
 Clio            Renault
 Clio            Renault
 Willys          Jeep
 Willys          Jeep
 Willys          Jeep
```

The SQL below will give me a result showing

```
Brand Name   Car 
JEEP         Willys
```

I would like to have every single Brand name and their best renting car. Not the best of all. 
Would love any help. Btw, I don't know how to use Inner joint, so if the solution could use the `where` clause, that would be awesome ! (Using Access)

(result wanted)

```
Brand Name   Car 
    JEEP         Willys
    RENAULT      Clio
```

--

```
  SELECT MARQUE.NOMMA AS [BRAND NAME], VEHICULE.MODELE AS [CAR NAME]
    FROM VEHICULE, MARQUE, LOUER
    WHERE MARQUE.CODEMA = VEHICULE.CODEMA
    AND VEHICULE.NOIMMAT = LOUER.NOIMMAT
    GROUP BY MARQUE.NOMMA, VEHICULE.MODELE, MARQUE.CODEMA
    HAVING COUNT(MARQUE.NOMMA) = ( SELECT max (NUMBER_OF_LOCATION)
                                    FROM (
                                            SELECT COUNT(MARQUE.NOMMA) as [NUMBER_OF_LOCATION]  
                                            FROM VEHICULE, MARQUE, LOUER
                                            WHERE MARQUE.CODEMA = VEHICULE.CODEMA
                                            AND VEHICULE.NOIMMAT = LOUER.NOIMMAT
                                            GROUP BY MARQUE.NOMMA, VEHICULE.MODELE


                                    ));
```

Here is the scheme

```
Vehicule(NoImmat, Modèle, DateAchat, CodeG#, CodeMA#)
Louer(CodeC#, NoImmat#, DateDebLoc, DateFinLoc, KmDeb, KmFin
Marque(CodeMA, NomMA, PaysMA, DateCreationMA, CodeTYCO#)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following on your data and got the desired results:

```
select car, brand 
from (select distinct car, brand, count(*) as cnt
             from test
             group by car)
group by brand
having cnt = max(cnt)
```